# override webview url depending on user selection

Tags: java, android, webview, android-alertdialog

I came across a situation which I think a common case but I'm having trouble to figure out the solution. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22246154/alertdialog-before-loading-url-in-webview) is what I found similar to my question but I dont understand how the solution worked for him. Can anybody points me the right way or explain the answer if its right.

I simply want to override the webview's url if user says `yes` otherwise no overriding, this is my piece of code

```
@Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            final boolean result[] = new boolean[1];
            builder.setTitle("Confirm");
            builder.setMessage("Are you sure to Finish Process?");

            builder.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    //some code

                    result[0] = true;
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }

            });

            builder.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // some code
                    result[0] = false;
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });

            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();
            return result[0];
```

}

I need that webview waits for the user response ,which is not happening right now and the boolean `result[0]` which is false initially was immediately returned.

Kindly point me if  I am missing any thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An AlertDialog does not block the UI thread.
While your AlertDialog is displayed it will not stop the WebView from continuing to update the UI with it's new url.

You'll need to initially prevent loading of the url, and then call `webview.loadUrl` again later once the user has made their decision.

```
private WebView mWebView;
private boolean mUserHasAllowedUrlLoading = false;
private String mUrl;
...

@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {       

    // Store the url
    mUrl = url;

    // Keep the WebView so we can access it again in the AlertDialog's anonymous inner classes
    mWebView = view;

    if (!mUserHasAllowedUrlLoading) {
        // This is the first time the url has attempted to load, so show the dialog.

        // Build and show AlertDialog
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Confirm");
        builder.setMessage("Are you sure to Finish Process?");

        builder.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                mUserHasAllowedUrlLoading = true;

                // Start loading the stored url again
                mWebView.loadUrl(mUrl);

                dialog.dismiss();
            }

        });

        builder.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();

        // We return true here so the WebView does not load anything for the moment
        return true;

    } else {
        // We can only get here if the user has already seen the dialog and clicked the positive button.

        // Reset the boolean so it's ready for next time the use tries to navigate away from the current page.
        mUserHasAllowedUrlLoading = false;

        // We return false this time so that the WebView actually loads the supplied url.
        return false;
    }
}
```